# Predicting Trending Product

Tags: python-3.x, regression

I am a beginner in Machine Learning . I want to build a model for predicting 
trending product. Can you please tell me in which layout and what parameters 
do I need in my dataset. Let's say I want to predict a certain product from certain category .So  I will be collecting dataset from various e-commerce sites e.g ebay, amazon  etc. of that category . 
Please tell me in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an dataset with features like

1. Number of sales
2. Ratings
3. Recommendations

And many more.
This is be a **classification** problem. You need to classify the products as trendy or not trendy. Also you will need labels which describe the data as trendy or not trendy.